# Modify the column value by other columns in r

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a CSV table (as a data frame). I want to modify a specific column value by other columns values.

I have prepared a code, but it doesn't work.
The data frame contains 1076 rows and 156 columns.

The formula have to be like this:

```
if (a[i,"0Q-state"] == "done" ) && (a[i,0Q-01] == NA))  a[i,0Q-01] = 0;
     else a[i,0Q-01] = a[i,0Q-01];
```

but I don't know how can I do this in r.

```
 >dataset4
       0Q-state   0Q-01 0Q-02 0Q-03 0Q-04 0Q-05 0Q-06 0Q-07 0Q-08 0Q-09
   1:  done        1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     NA
   2:              1     1     1     1     1     1     NA    1     1
   3:  done        1     1     1     NA    1     1     1     1     1
   5:  done        1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
   6:  done        1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
   7:              1     1     NA    1     0     0     0     1     0
   8:  done        1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0


   sapply(c("0Q-01","0Q-02","0Q-03","0Q-04","0Q-05","0Q-06","0Q-07","0Q-08","0Q-09"), 
   function(y) {
   dataset4[,y] <- sapply(c(1:1076), function(x) 
   ifelse (((is.na(dataset4[x,y])) && (dataset4[x,c("0Q-state")] == "done")) 
   ,0, dataset4[x,y]))}
    )
```

Output has to be:

```
     >dataset4
       0Q-state   0Q-01 0Q-02 0Q-03 0Q-04 0Q-05 0Q-06 0Q-07 0Q-08 0Q-09
   1:  done        1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
   2:              1     1     1     1     1     1     NA    1     1
   3:  done        1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1
   5:  done        1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
   6:  done        1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
   7:              1     1     NA    1     0     0     0     1     0
   8:  done        1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
```

Answer (score 1):

we could try:

```
df[rep(df[, 1] == "done", ncol(df)) & is.na(df)] <- 0
df

1     done        1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
2                 1     1     1     1     1     1     NA    1     1
3     done        1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1
4     done        1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
5     done        1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
6                 1     1     NA    1     0     0     0     1     0
7     done        1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
```

or using `sapply()`:

```
myFunc <- function(x, y) ifelse(is.na(x) & y == "done", 1, x)  
data.frame(df[, 1], sapply(df[, -1], myFunc, y = df[, 1]))

1 done  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  NA
2       1  1  1  1  1  1 NA  1   1
3 done  1  1  1 NA  1  1  1  1   1
4 done  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1   0
5 done  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1   0
6       1  1 NA  1  0  0  0  1   0
7 done  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1   0
```

where you can always substitute `df[, 1]` with `df[, "0Q-state"]` and `df[, -1]` with `df[, namesOfDummyVars]`

Comment: Thanks! Great sample. Perhaps... You know, how can I iterate the column automatically?

Comment: sure, included an `sapply()`-approach.

Comment: btw. use `dput()` on your data and paste it in next time. It will make it easier for people to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The question has been tagged with `data.table` and the printed output of `dataset4` suggests that `dataset4` already is a `data.table` object.

Here are three variants in `data.table` syntax to replace NAs in rows which are marked as "done".

```
# create vector of names of columns to be changed 
cols <- sprintf("0Q-%02i", 1:9)

# variant 1
dataset4[`0Q-state` == "done", 
         (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 0L)), 
         .SDcols = cols][]
```

> ```
>    0Q-state 0Q-01 0Q-02 0Q-03 0Q-04 0Q-05 0Q-06 0Q-07 0Q-08 0Q-09
> 1:     done     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
> 2:              1     1     1     1     1    NA     1     1    NA
> 3:     done     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1
> 4:     done     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
> 5:     done     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
> 6:              1    NA     1     0     0     0     1     0    NA
> 7:     done     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
> ```

or

```
# variant 2
lapply(cols, function(i) dataset4[`0Q-state` == "done" & is.na(get(i)), (i) := 0L])
dataset4
```

returning the same as above

or

```
# variant 3  --- data.table development version 1.10.5
for (i in cols) 
  set(dataset4, which(dataset4[, "0Q-state"] == "done" & is.na(dataset4[, ..i])), i, 0L)
dataset4
```